# Congratulations! Data Science is graduating!

Tags: discussion, graduation

You've been cleared for graduation by the Stack Exchange Community Team! Data Science met our threshold for [graduation-worthy sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites) and after a review, the Community Team determined that you're good to go. Reaching 'mature community' status is a big milestone, and you should be very proud.

What does this mean exactly? Graduation works in two phases. Starting today, you'll receive the following benefits:

- You will have an election for community moderators - we currently have a somewhat backed up election schedule that got bumped a bit, so your election is currently set to begin collecting questions on **July 24th**.
- You will no longer see the "beta" label attached to your site's name
- You will become eligible for question migration paths with the rest of the network
- You will soon be able to select your own community ads. This thread will go up probably next week as we have another graduation setup and this will allow us to batch handle the hookups.

The site will still receive a full design from one of our designers, which will be packaged with an increase in the amount of reputation needed to access each privilege. It's no secret that our backlog for site designs is long, so instead of making you wait to receive all the parts of graduation at once, we wanted to [give you the things we could give](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260754/feedback-requested-design-independent-graduation) you now. We think we've hammered out most of the bugs in the process,, but there are still likely to be some left -  so if you come across anything out of place, please report it on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) using the [graduating-sites] tag.

This site has reached this point because of your generous contributions. Together, you've created a valuable resource that helps people. Congratulations on all you've accomplished.